# Как расположить блоки

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Как расположить блоки как на скриншоте.

[image: Как нужно:]

[image: Как сейчас:]

Comment: Вы просите сверстать за вас? Расположение блоков - обыкновенное. Что вы сами сделали, чтобы решить свою задачу? Где ваш пример кода, добавьте его в вопрос? Что именно не получилось?

Comment: Если ответ на вопрос был исчерпывающим, пожалуйста, подтвердите его как решенный.

Answer (score 3):

**Flex + Float**

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 2rem 15px 0;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  .container {
    display: block;
  }
}

.title-holder {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
}

.desc-holder {}

.img-holder {
  max-width: 50%;
  order: 1;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  .img-holder {
    float: right;
  }
}

.sign-holder {
  align-self: flex-end;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #eaeaea;
}

img {
  width: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="img-holder">
    <img src="https://www.foxrc.com/wp-content/themes/frc/static/images/plate1.png" alt="Plate">
  </div>
  <div class="title-holder">
    <h1>Title</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="desc-holder">
    <p>
      Dramatically reintermediate B2C metrics after cooperative methods of empowerment. Progressively utilize an expanded array of process improvements before one-to-one growth strategies.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="sign-holder">
    Sign
  </div>

</div>
```

Можно построить и без `float`, но тогда прийдеться ограничивать высоту flex-контейнера

**CSS Grid**

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 50% 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "title title title" "desc desc desc" "sign img .";
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 2rem 15px 0;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  .container {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: "title img" "desc img" "sign img";
  }
}

.title-holder {
  grid-area: title;
}

.desc-holder {
  grid-area: desc;
}

.img-holder {
  grid-area: img;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 799px) {
  .img-holder {
    grid-area: img;
    height: 300px;
    text-align: center;
  }
}

.sign-holder {
  grid-area: sign;
  align-self: end;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #eaeaea;
}

img {
  width: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="title-holder">
    <h1>Title</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="desc-holder">
    <p>
      Dramatically reintermediate B2C metrics after cooperative methods of empowerment. Progressively utilize an expanded array of process improvements before one-to-one growth strategies.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="sign-holder">
    Sign
  </div>
  <div class="img-holder">
    <img src="https://www.foxrc.com/wp-content/themes/frc/static/images/plate1.png" alt="Plate">
  </div>
</div>
```

**Float + Absolute**

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 2rem 15px 0;
}

.info-holder {
  width: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  .info-holder {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
  }
}

.img-holder {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .img-holder {
    margin: auto;
    float: none;
  }
}

.sign-holder {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #eaeaea;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .sign-holder {
    position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;}
} 

img {
  width: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="info-holder">
    <div class="title-holder">
      <h1>Title</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="desc-holder">
      <p>
        Dramatically reintermediate B2C metrics after cooperative methods of empowerment. Progressively utilize an expanded array of process improvements before one-to-one growth strategies.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="sign-holder">
      Sign
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="img-holder">
    <img src="https://www.foxrc.com/wp-content/themes/frc/static/images/plate1.png" alt="Plate">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Похоже на то что нужно, но тайтл с текстом и подписью, должны быть  одним блоком, а тарелка вторым, и вообщем чтобы они были в одном блоке вместе централизованны относительно размера контейнера.

Comment: Добавил еще вариант. Это все демо примеры с размерами взятыми на глаз, поэтому когда вы будете делать свою работу, то поправить центровку вам не составит труда.

Comment: Вместо того, чтобы еще и правки выставлять, составьте вопрос в соответствии с требованиями сайта, с примером кода, что вы вложили в решение задачи? Вы просите сделать работу БЕСПЛАТНО за вас! @E_K не поощряйте халявщиков!

Comment: @kizoso, тоже об этом подумл но, уже после ответа. Так что буду имметь ввиду. Спасибо.